# Comparing two hashsets

Tags: c#

I have two hashsets that are loading data from two different text files.
The contents of both text files look as follows:

```
name/12441431252132
name1/323244231244142
name2/32423452524234
```

My code to currently load both files and make sure i only have unique results from textFile2:

```
HashSet<string> txt1 = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines("textFile1.txt"));
HashSet<string> txt2 = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines("textFile2.txt"));

txt2.ExceptWith(txt1);
```

My problem is that it only removes lines based on the criteria if the whole line matches. I want to remove It based on the name basis instead. For example, name2 should never be included if its in textFile1 even if the id's after the / are different.

How would i accomplish this?

Let me know if my explanation is not good i will try to improve it - and please excuse my english!

Comment: Are the names in each text file unique?

Comment: Not always there can be more than 1 of the same in textfile1, but if they are it should never be included after the ExceptWith in txt2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add some string splitting to separate names and the rest of the content - the approach is a little "dirty" so in real code I would probably use foreach loops and introduce dedicated classes:

```
var content = File.ReadLines("textFile1.txt").Select(line => 
{
    var parts = line.Split('/');
    return new 
    { 
        Name = parts[0],
        Content = parts[1]
    };
});

HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>(content.Select(c=> c.Name));
HashSet<string> txt2 = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines("textFile2.txt"));
var uniques = txt2.Where(line => !names.Contains(line.Split('/')[0]));
```

Comment: How would i get the first unique name and ID from the uniques var? later on in the code i need to use the first ones and make them into strings

Comment: @hariette: It wasn't clear to me that you wanted to separate out the lines into Name/Value pairs for `txt2` as well - in that case just use the same approach as used for the `contents` parsing

Answer (score 0):

if you split by `/`, you can build a HashSet of names that appear in the first set, then pick the items in the second set that have a name that does not appear in the first set.

```
var nameValues1=
    File
     .ReadLines(fileName)
     .Select(line=>line.Split('/'))
     .Select(parts=>new {name=parts[0],value=parts[1]});
var nameValues2=
    File
     .ReadLines(fileName2)
     .Select(line=>line.Split('/'))
     .Select(parts=>new {name=parts[0],value=parts[1]});
var names1=new HashSet<string>(nameValues1.Select(nv=>nv.name);
var result=
    nameValues2
     .Where(nv=>!names1.Contains(nv.name))
     .Select(nv=>string.Format("{0}/{1}",nv.name,nv.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that a `HashSet` is still the best choice? Here is a different approach using a `Dictionary<String, String>`:

```
var lines1 = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path1);
var lines2 = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path2);
var allItems = new Dictionary<String, String>();
foreach (var line in lines1.Concat(lines2))
{
    String[] tokens = line.Split('/');
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
    {
        String name = tokens[0];
        String number = tokens[1];
        if (!allItems.ContainsKey(name))
            allItems.Add(name, number);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's problematic, given the OP states that names in a file are **not** unique.

Comment: @spender: But his requirement is to filter out the duplicate names. Above approach would override existing names' numbers, but could  be changed easily to do something else.

Comment: @spender: Since OP just want to take the first, i've edited above to check for existence with `ContainsKey`.